# Can I rely on `curl` being installed on Debian/Ubuntu? How could I find out?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, apt, dependencies, defaults

Is `curl` installed by default on Debian & Ubuntu (in 2024)? How could I answer this question myself?

I am writing the install instructions for software, part of which requires running a script that downloads some data from the web with curl. Can I rely on `curl` being available on a standard, current “stable”/LTS (i) Debian Desktop, (ii) Debian Server (iii) Ubuntu Desktop & (iv) Ubuntu Server? Or do I need to include `sudo apt install curl` in the install instructions? I would like to keep the instructions simple, and not included unneeded things.

How could I answer this question myself? I tried a standard Vagrant ubuntu image, and it had curl, but I'm unsure if that's the default *for Ubuntu* or if this has been made this way. I tried looking at debian, but I'm not sure how tasksel fits into this, or works. Is there some bash snippet I can run on my Debian desktop to tell me if package X is installed by default?

Comment: What is Debian Desktop?

Comment: Consider distributing your software in packages and then you can rely on the package manager to ensure that all dependancies get installed as well. - Note that downloading data directly from the internet is in many companies not possible and users will be required to for example use a proxy so making instructions both simple and completely idiot proof can be challenging. I usually go with the assumption that the people who should ; usually don't read the manual anyway and that the ones who do, well they didn't get root rights because they're idiots and should be able to read an error message.

Comment: So; in scripts always capture errors and generate useful error messages, including for missing dependancies. And I  then prefer to let an operator deal with them.  When you're not automating for your own environment, you don't have all the information and assumptions on how to solve certain errors like missing dependancies are always going to be incorrect for some use cases. So don't solve them and generate a useful error for the person who can (attempt to) solve the error

Comment: Both Debian and Ubuntu docker images don't have `curl` by default.

Answer (score 2):

We Usually do not code for you, as it might easy with some research.

However, since i already have something prepared in the past i have something for you:

## 1. Only Check

```
#!/bin/bash

# Check if the curl package is installed
if dpkg -l | grep -q "curl"; then
    echo "curl is installed."
else
    echo "curl is not installed."
fi
```

## 2. Auto install

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Check if the curl package is installed
if dpkg -l | grep -q "curl"; then
    echo "curl is installed."
else
    echo "curl is not installed."
        sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install curl
fi
```

## 3. Ask for installation

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Check if the curl package is installed
if dpkg -l | grep -q "curl"; then
    echo "curl is installed."
else
    echo "curl is not installed."
    read -p "Do you want to install curl? (y/n): " choice
    if [ "$choice" = "y" ]; then
        sudo apt-get update
        sudo apt-get install curl
    fi
fi
```

i think you get now the idea.

## Can you relay on curl should be avaible?

It Depends. For scripting, always consider, if a minimalist system is installed, I would run another round to check a requirement, and then implement the thing.

Comment: Although the question asks about the `curl` package, the dependancy is on the `curl` command ; so in a bash script something like `command -v curl >/dev/null 2>&1 || { echo >&2 "curl is required to download bar-data but curl is not installed or found in $PATH.  Aborting."; exit 1; }`  might be a better check that will also catch situations where `curl` is installed but $PATH gets severely limited and simply running `curl` without an absolute /path/to/bin/curl fails

Comment: Code above will indeed give inconsistent results - e.g. `dpkg -l | grep -q "curl"` will match libcurl and php-curl neither of which have dependency on the 'curl' CLI tool. `apt policy curl` would give a better indicator if it has been installed (but IIRC will require parsing of stdout) or use `which curl`

Answer (score 1):

> Is curl installed by default on Debian & Ubuntu (in 2024)?

No but it's very very common.

> How could I answer this question myself?

$ which curl

If you get a path to the binary in reply, it's on your system.

Or:

$ curl -h

If you get the curl helpfile to stdout, it's on your system.

Comment: Note that `which` is also a separate package and binary so if you're afraid of very minimal systems consider using  the bash builtin command `command`  for an even more light-weight and better check  to confirm if `curl` exists in your $PATH.

Comment: `which curl` will tell me that curl is installed. It will not tell me if curl is installed by default on ubuntu desktop, which is what I was asking with the question “how could I answer this myself?”

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to keep the instructions simple

Ubuntu can be installed in a minimized form, or maybe the user removed `curl` for some reason (ie: the security issue reported some months ago).

So, precisely to keep things simple, I would include `sudo apt install curl` to shield your guide from any issue due to the missing package. Maybe you can even merge this command with some previous `apt` runs.

If you really want to test for `curl` before calling `apt`, you can use something as

`command -v curl || sudo apt install curl`

Comment: And hope that sudo is installed.

Comment: which is for a standard debian not ;)